# unable to connect android phone with localhost

Tags: android, localhost, wamp

I have developed an android application in eclipse.And i used wamp server for server connection.Initially,i gave url as 10.0.2.2:portno in java page for connection to localhost.It worked properly in my emulator.Later i tried to run the app in my android device.
I changed the url using the local ipv4 address as 192.x.x.x accordingly. And connected my laptop and mobile using wifi hotspot. The problem is though i have done all the steps right,iam unable to access the localhost. Kindly help me..

Comment: You have connected your laptop to mobile wifi hotspot?

Comment: Are you able to call the 192.x.x.x url from your phone browser?

Comment: no.It takes too long to load.And then its like "The page cannot be loaded"

Comment: Your network setup is not right. Both the laptop and mobile has to be on the same network.

Comment: i connected my laptop and mobile using mobile's portable wifi hotspot.

Comment: That does not necessarily make them on the same network. Your mobile will be connected to your Network Provider and for the laptop the mobile is the service provider. So they are on different networks. On your phone check your IP (Settings > Status > IP Address). Compare it with your laptops IP address. They should be in the same range.

Comment: You have no control over the HOTSPOT's network. It could be blocking all sorts of things and you would never know or be able to check

Comment: they are not same.my phone ipaddress is 100.x.x.x.what should i do now?can you explain in detail

Comment: So they are on different networks. You cant connect them if they are on different networks. if you have hosting services, try hosting it on a server.

Comment: You could try and set your phone to use the hotspot wifi as well as the other device

Comment: no.I tried with another hosting service.Still its not working

Comment: Did u call it from browser?